# adding a datatable in a dataset

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset

I'm adding a datatable to a dataset like this:

```
DataTable dtImage = new DataTable();
//some updates in the Datatable
ds.Tables.Add(dtImage);
```

But the next time, when the datatable gets updated, will it be reflected in the dataset? or we need to write some code to make it reflected?

Also, I'm checking the dataset if the datatable exists in the dataset already using:

```
if(!ds.Tables.Contains("dtImage"))
    ds.Tables.Add(dtImage);
```

In the first iteration, `ds.Tables.Contains("dtImage")` is false, so, `ds.Tables.Add(dtImage)`
 adds the table to the dataset. But in the second iteration, `ds.Tables.Contains("dtImage")` is false again, but `ds.Tables.Add(dtImage)` throws an error:

> Datatable already belongs to this dataset.

If the dataset doesn't contain the datatable named "dtImage", why is it throwing an error?

**Update: Thanks, that issue got solved. Pls answer this:**

> But the next time, when the datatable gets updated, will it be
>   reflected in the dataset? or we need to write some code to make it
>   reflected?

Comment: what does your code look like for creating the datatable? Did you name it dtImage -> Dim dtImage as DataTable = New DataTable("dtImage")

Comment: Because you are providing hardcoded value to `ds.tables.Contains("");` method....Check it using `ds.Tables.contains(footable.tablename);`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume that you haven't set the `TableName` property of the DataTable, for example via constructor:

```
var tbl = new DataTable("dtImage");
```

If you don't provide a name, it will be automatically created with `"Table1"`, the next table will get `"Table2"` and so on.

Then the solution would be to provide the `TableName` and then check with `Contains(nameOfTable)`.

To **clarify** it: You'll get an `ArgumentException` if that DataTable already belongs to the DataSet (the same reference). You'll get a `DuplicateNameException` if there's already a DataTable in the DataSet with the same name(not case-sensitive).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as4zy2kc.aspx

Comment: Oh thanks, is it that why the first time, it doesn't throw an error? So, the second time too, it'll try to create with the table name "Table1"?

Comment: @ManikandanSigamani: I trhink that was misunderstandable, i meant that the TableName will be created with consecutive numers at the end, so `Tabel1,Table2,Table3,...`. So since you haven't provided a name, it will always be unique and Contains returns false. But when you add the same reference of a DataTable, you'll get the exception. If the name would be the problem, you wouldn't get an `ArgumentException`(...already belongs...) but a `DuplicateNameException`.

Comment: Wow that stayed like a nail in woods, thanks for the explanation @TimSchmelter:)

Answer (score 6):

you have to set the tableName you want to your dtimage that is for instance

```
dtImage.TableName="mydtimage";


if(!ds.Tables.Contains(dtImage.TableName))
        ds.Tables.Add(dtImage);
```

it will be reflected in dataset because dataset is a container of your datatable dtimage
    and you have a reference on your dtimage

Answer (score 6):

**Just give any name to the DataTable Like:**

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = SecondDataTable.Copy();    
dt .TableName = "New Name";
DataSet.Tables.Add(dt );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable activity = DTsetgvActivity.Copy();
activity.TableName = "activity";
ds.Tables.Add(activity);

DataTable Honer = DTsetgvHoner.Copy();
Honer.TableName = "Honer";
ds.Tables.Add(Honer);

DataTable Property = DTsetgvProperty.Copy();
Property.TableName = "Property";
ds.Tables.Add(Property);


DataTable Income = DTsetgvIncome.Copy();
Income.TableName = "Income";
ds.Tables.Add(Income);

DataTable Dependant = DTsetgvDependant.Copy();
Dependant.TableName = "Dependant";
ds.Tables.Add(Dependant);

DataTable Insurance = DTsetgvInsurance.Copy();
Insurance.TableName = "Insurance";
ds.Tables.Add(Insurance);

DataTable Sacrifice = DTsetgvSacrifice.Copy();
Sacrifice.TableName = "Sacrifice";
ds.Tables.Add(Sacrifice);

DataTable Request = DTsetgvRequest.Copy();
Request.TableName = "Request";
ds.Tables.Add(Request);

DataTable Branchs = DTsetgvBranchs.Copy();
Branchs.TableName = "Branchs";
ds.Tables.Add(Branchs);
```